# Download images from sequence of galleries?

Tags: windows, powershell

Anyone know of any software or a script for downloading images from a sequence of galleries? Where the galleries are on pages like `www.example.com/1` ... `www.example.com/9999` and each page has a bunch of thumbnails directly linked to the full size image?

I've been trying [wget](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) with something like `wget -A.JPG -r -l1 -np www.example.com/1` but that gets the thumbnails too, which I don't want, and I don't know how to make it download a sequence of pages.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is exactly the effect you're after, but try `--no-parent` in your wget approach.  It won't download the files from the parent directories.  This won't help much in the case of a deep tree, but looks like you just have 1 level to deal with.

Any more complex & I would wrap wget in a script.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using a script. Check out the [wget man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wget), specifically the `--follow-tags` and `--ignore-tags` switches, which can help you follow and ignore certain html tags (you can then avoid downloading the thumbnails and just following the `<a>` tags to the full size images). To loop in a script you'll want something like this:

```
for ($i = 1;$i -le 9999;$i++)
{
     iex "C:\path\to\wget.exe -A.JPG -r -l1 -np www.example.com/$i"
}
```

as you have not provided the site, we can only assume it's layout by your description. Best of luck!